# Where to find comprehensive Forge documentation?

Tags: minecraft-modding

There are a lot of things I'm trying to accomplish with a Minecraft mod. Some of it seems rather academic but finding a complete source of documentation is, well ... something for which I should hire Sherlock Holmes.

Is there a comprehensive source for documentation? Where is it?

Comment: StackExchange is not a good place to ask for links to external resources, because those links can rot, while a StackExchange answer is meant to be useful to readers in the indefinite future. This site works best when you want something that can be answered/explained in the body of an answer post, so that answer remains useful even after all links have broken.

Comment: A [web search for *minecraft forge documentation*](https://www.bing.com/search?q=minecraft+forge+documentation) gave me [the official docs](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/latest/) on the first hit.

Comment: @Pikalek: thanks ... but it's far from comprehensive. What's seems clear to me is that modders like having information in their heads rather than on paper where everyone else can find it.